# Multiple wildcards in excel filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, wildcards

Can I use multiple wildcards when I'm filtering data on a specific column? I have a table (20K+ records) with dollar amounts and I need to find all that contain cents. I've tried &#9734.&#9734 in my search but it isn't returning results.

Answer (score 0):

Use the INT function.  By definition an INTeger cannot contain fractions... Only while numbers.

.   If(A1=Int(A1), "",A1)

Thus formula will give you all values with decimals.

Comment: @darinsq10: What wbeard52 is not saying is that you would need to establish a “helper column” to hold his formula.  Since you asked about filtering, what you may want to do is define the helper column to be simply `=A1=INT(A1)`, which will be TRUE for integers (e.g., 0, 1, and 42) and FALSE for non-integers (e.g., 0.17, 1.23, and 3.14).  Then you can filter on that.    ...    /    ...    By the way, what do you mean by &#9734.&#9734?